# Spring not autowiring using annotation a bean declared on the XML

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, ejb

I'm trying to inject a bean that was defined on a XML into an annotated,  It is only annotated and not declared on XML, I think that is just something that I'm missing here is my *context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">
...
<bean id="userBusiness" class="org.springframework.ejb.access.LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:global/app-common/app-common-core/UserBusinessImpl" />
    <property name="businessInterface" value="com.app.common.business.UserBusiness" />
</bean>
...
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.app.common.jsf" />
</beans>
```

Here's the component:

```
@Component
public class AppAuthorization {

    @Autowired
    private UserBusiness userBusiness;

    @Autowired
    private AppLogin sabiusLogin;
...

@Local
public interface UserBusiness {
    User listUserByFilter(User user) throws UserBusinessException;
...

@Stateless
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.DEFAULT)
@Interceptors({SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class})
public class UserBusinessImpl implements UserBusiness {

    @Autowired
    private ProgramasUsuariosDao programasUsuariosDao;
...
```

When I try to access the AppAuthorization Spring says that:

```
Could not autowire field: private com.app.common.business.UserBusiness com.app.common.jsf.AppAuthorization.userBusiness"
```

Seems that the annotated bean can't see the declared one, but search and seems that I only needed to add the annotation-config to the XML, is this right? Hope some can help me.

**EDIT**

I think that this is the most important part of the stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.app.common.business.UserBusiness] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:997)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:867)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:779)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:503)
    ... 201 more
```

Following the steps on the context creation I see no bean registered tha can be seen by annotations just when springs creates the context based on the xml is that I can see all the beans that wre created.

**EDIT 2**

This is the beanRefContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="contexts" class="com.app.common.spring.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext" />
</beans>
```

This is the class that loads the XML context files:

```
public class ClassPathXmlApplicationContext extends org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext {

    public ClassPathXmlApplicationContext() {       
        super((System.getProperty("module.context.file").split(";")));
    }

}
```

As I said, the annotated beans cannot see the XML ones so, spring cannot autowire them.

**EDIT 3**

I don't have a `@Configuration` bean (I'm not using AnnotationConfigApplicationContext), all the config is in the XML and if I try to create one the server doesn't start, it's a legacy system with spring 3.2 and EJB 3.0 and I can't change this aspect now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show full stacktrace? Spring usually tells why autowiring failed.

Comment: In xml `userBusiness` has type `LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean` but in java you use `com.app.common.business.UserBusiness`. In xml you tell spring to register `LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean` as bean with name `userBusiness` and in java you autowire different class`com.app.common.business.UserBusiness`

Comment: Hi @JaySmith, LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean is a bean exclusive for inject EJBs, it handles the type conversion. UserBusiness receives the UserBusinessImpl stateless EJB.

Comment: @JoelSantos where are you importing the XML file to let Spring creates the beans defined there?

Comment: I believe you're missing beans component scan

Comment: Can you post the definition of  `UserBusiness` class as well?

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to specify `@Component` annotation for the  `UserBusiness` class

EDIT:

Can you make the `component-scan` config to `com.app.common` instead of `com.app.common.jsf`

Comment: Hi @anup0513, it is declared on the xml, is an EJB that is created with spring LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean

Comment: @JoelSantos Can you try the edit? I think the component-scan is configured for `com.app.common.jsf`

Comment: I tried, but it gets the same problem because of the Spring-EJB integration. The UserBusiness has `@Autowired` beans and because they can't see what is mapped on the XML I receive the same exception for other fields.

Answer (score 0):

What seems to work was create a `@Configuration` import the xml that have the bean declaration (with `@ImportResource`) and don't scan it's package in XML. 
For some reason if I declare the file in the XML the server don't start, it's strange because I have no definition anywhere that I'm using an annotation configuration.